# How to count number of columns in csv python?

Tags: python, csv

```
dic = {}
counter = 0 

years = ['2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008',
        '2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016', '2017']

for y in years:
    dic[y] = 0

with open(file_path) as csvf:
    reader = csv.reader(csvf)
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:

        dic[row[0]] += int(row[1])
        print(dic)

years, average_grades = [], []
# YOUR CODE HERE
return years, average_grades
```

What I am trying to do here is, I am trying to read through a csv file which contains a row with a year and numbers (could be 0 or more than 0).

I eventually have to store

[year] and [average value corresponding to the year]

I am trying to add all values in the value of the key(year) and divide at the end by the number of cols it has.

But I am kind of stuck how to get the number of cols in that row.

Help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for number of columns in each row of CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715410/check-for-number-of-columns-in-each-row-of-csv)

Comment: As a general rule you **should** always share sample data to make it easy to understand your difficulty. -1